# Help with SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Got two tables: `users(id, column)` and `objects(user_id, column)`.
How to extract all users who don't have any corresponding object?
I'm using MySQL.

Comment: Post your exact tables and maybe some tests youdid :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should suffice, left outer join to keep all users then remove any which have a corresponding object.

```
Select * 
from
   users u left outer join
   objects o on u.[id] = o.user_id
where
   o.user_id is null
```

Comment: You need left Join, not inner Join.

Comment: if `o.user_id` is null that means the user has no objects joined to him

Comment: @Adam Matan - that was cack handedness on my part, already edited it to correct

Comment: @kehz - standard convention means `null = null` evaluates to false

Answer (score 3):

You should use a join.

For instance:

```
SELECT u.id, o.id 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN objects o ON o.user_id = u.id 
WHERE o.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT usr.id
FROM users usr LEFT OUTER JOIN objects obj
ON usr.id=obj.user_id 
WHERE usr.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
WHERE u.id not in
(SELECT o.user_id
FROM objects o)
```